# Building a framework in Java for helping people lose weight through exercise recommendation

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller, frameworks, software-design

For my final project in my Computer Engineering program, I have chosen to make a framework that helps people lose weight by recommending how much exercise the user should do. Terrible idea... But now I am stuck with it, so might as well just make it work.
As for the algorithms of recommendation, I pretty much got all of that covered, so it isn't the issue.

The issues I am having are with organizing all of this in the shape of a framework, I must admit I am completely lost. My professor/project supervisor wants me to use the MVC pattern for it, but I can't see how I can make this work, specially since it's main use is going to be for Android. My original plan was to not include the GUI, that way, developers could also use it for Desktop applications, but my professor demanded I do include it.

As it stands I have a layered architecture that my professor approved,but I really do not see how I can implement it. Here it is: 
[image: Layered Architecture]

So basically what I am asking for is some insight on how to take this layered architecture, or just the concept for that matter and make the class diagram for it or at least have an idea on how to begin the implementation.

Thanks in advance. Any help will be useful.

Comment: Your professor approved that as an "architecture"? Are you sure?

Comment: Is each layer (or the box in a layer) intended to be a [Finite State Machine](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/umlfsm.pdf)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The professor might have had to approve 200 or so such diagrams.  He/she probably looked quickly at the picture, saw that it looked vaguely multi-tiered, and didn't even bother to read the words.

Comment: @DavidWallace Presentation at the top and persistence at the bottom. Ship it!

Comment: The more thought I give to this question, the more it bothers me. I mean, I know what a framework is. But a framework to help people lose weight? Somehow, I don't get it at all. I can imagine a program that helps people lose weight, and recommends exercise. But I don't see how a framework would do it, or what sort of programs you'd write in that framework. Can you please clarify what you think your finished product will look like?

Comment: Ok... So the comments here are honestly starting to scare me.
The professor actually suggested this architecture for me,as far as I am concerned, I had a completely different idea in mind that he completely scrapped.
Each box in a layer is a package, with a set of classes in it.
Finally, about it being a framework. My original idea was for it to be an application, but my professor thought it wouldn't be good enough so told me to do a framework. 
I am not at all happy with it, and if I could change it I would. As of now, I just need some insight on how to move on.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: As for the finished product, I just imagine something with ready to use algorithms that recommends exercise depending on the user's objectives. It will include a calorie counter, running monitor and walking monitor. The idea is to make it a way that developers can reuse the code to make different applications. As simple as that.

Comment: Oh, that sounds like a library, not a framework.  I guess that doesn't sound quite so painful.  I'm not quite sure how to help you though, but I'd like to.  Do you see the different features that you provide as fitting in to the different rectangles in your diagram?

Comment: Yeah... The way I thought of it was more like a library, but I need to make it into a framework somehow. It has been quite painful indeed regardless.
I am sorry, but I don't think I understand your question. What do you mean? Like the different features of the framework? Or different programs that could be made with it?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't see your latest reply until now.  (It's a good idea to put a person's name with the @ sign at the front if you want them to see a message).  I hope it's not too late to help you further.  I guess I meant the features of the framework.  I imagine your framework giving you a basic application in which individual programmers add certain features; for example, certain calculations.  Is that how you saw it?

Comment: Sorry about that @DavidWallace.I guess I am still sortav new to the community.
It is never too late to help me further and I accept everything I can get.
My idea is to create applications that the user can monitor it's running activities, calorie counts based on the type of exercise he or she has done and walk monitors for who just wants to live a simple life. There are also parameters that I use to generate these recommendations which are distance, velocity, time and cardiac frequency.
The idea is to make an app where the user inserts two of those parameters and the application will generate

Comment: a recommendation based on what are the users objectives (lose weight or do the minimum to be healthy or improve running).
I also will have the function to analyse what the use will be doing, which will give him feedback on how to improve what he is doing.